# Django form misbehaving under POST request

Tags: python, django, forms

When I send a get request to the server POST method also gets executed and gives me an error that bookForm variable has not been initialized. My question is when i hit a GET request, POST method code should never get executed! Also how do i resolve this issue.
Error that django prints :  local variable 'bookForm' referenced before assignment ( at line where it is first referenced...here its bookForm.isValid() call.)

```
def main(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        bookForm = BookForm(request.POST)

        # check whether it's valid:

        if bookForm.is_valid():

            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required

        return HttpResponse('<h1>Page was found</h1>')

    else:

        bookForm = BookForm()

    return render(request,'home.html',{'bookForm':bookForm,})
```

Comment: Is that the correct indentation that you're using in your code??

Comment: I don't know you tell me, specifically is the else at the same level as the first if statement? Have you tried setting a breakpoint?

Comment: @Sayse Indentation is correct...I have checked the indentation like 10 times by now...it has no indentation related issue.

Comment: @Sayse I just rewrote the code and now it works...turns out it was an indentation issue only...but I checked my last code again...indentation was correct...I'm still wondering why it wasnt working. But anyways thanx for your help :)

Comment: No worries, was the only explanation I could see

Comment: I would like correct your assumption about POST/GET priority - if there are (somehow) both elements present, the request.method is POST, even when GET dictionary contains also some items. So when your form have method=POST, no variables at all and action "myurl?a=1&b=2" it is still POST method.

Comment: @AkashTomar it may be also cause you have a mixture of spaces and tabs and this could make also a such conflicts.